# VBA max date range in excel from access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

new at vba. I have an Access database that updates an excel workbook. What I have so far it that is appends the set of records to the bottom of a data tab.

What I need to build is that before it appends the data I need for VBA to check the workbook for today's date in the Date column on the data tab. If it finds today's date, it shouldn't append the data.

I know i need to either max(date column) or DMax but I am lost on how to build this.
completely confused myself, so instead of getting more in the weeds I am asking for help.

```
Public Sub max_Click()

verintreportTemplate2 = "Template_VerintSchedulesResults_EST.xlsx"
reporttemplatelocation = "\Customer Service\Midwest\OH Group01\EntSchedAndForecast\BackUpDocs\NEW_DATABASE\Schedules_Process\Report_Templates\"
Drive = "z:"

Dim appExcel As Object

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With .Workbooks.Open(Drive & reporttemplatelocation & verintreportTemplate2)
.Worksheets ("DOW Summary Data")
'dateMax = DMax("Weekof")
```

so I stopped at this point.

Comment: I'm confused. Where is the date, in excel or access? And do you export from access to excel or the other way around?

Comment: Why not have Excel link to Access table or query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If workbook structure is simple (single row column headers in first row), open a recordset using worksheet as data source. If worksheet has a complicated structure, specify a range or different approach will be needed.

Grab date value from record.

```
Public Sub max_Click()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

verintreportTemplate2 = "Template_VerintSchedulesResults_EST.xlsx"
reporttemplatelocation = "\Customer Service\Midwest\OH Group01\EntSchedAndForecast\BackUpDocs\NEW_DATABASE\Schedules_Process\Report_Templates\"
Drive = "z:"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Drive & reporttemplatelocation & verintreportTemplate2 _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
rs.Open "SELECT Max(Weekof) AS MaxDate FROM [DOW Summary Data$]", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If Date() <> rs!MaxDate Then
'do something
End If
End Sub
```